# Grafana loki backups using boltdb as storage

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, grafana-loki

I installed grafana loki v1.5 it yesterday using docker, it's been running for 21 hs using boltdb. When I look into the /loki/index dir I see there are 112 files named index_2519 through index_2630. 
In the configuration the schema_config.index period is set to 168h.

What is the relationship between this value and the files created?

If I want to backup the logs for a specified period of time, what files should I copy from the index and chunks dir?

Comment: Here are some operational details of Loki 2.x boltdb-shipper https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/operations/storage/boltdb-shipper/#operational-details

Answer (score 1):

Loki 2.0+ added a new "Single Store" mechanism called "boltdb-shipper".

It will locally store indexes in BoltDB files and keep shipping those files to a shared object storage i.e the same object storage used for storing chunks.

https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/operations/storage/boltdb-shipper

So you don't have to worry about backup as long as you can correctly configure the shared object storage for "boltdb-shipper".

Of course, under certain circumstances, you might still need backup the shared object storage or at least enforce "WORM: write-once-read-many" policy. However, that will be out scope of Loki.